Get all FeatureFlags with a filter
I'm using a FeatureManager to handle all my feature and some of them have a filter that will query my Db.
It allows me to have something similar to Azure AppConfiguration but without spending anything.
"FeatureManagement": {
  "FEATURE_USER_GET_NOTIFIED": {
    "EnabledFor": [
      {
        "Name": "FeatureForSpecificUser"
      }
    ]
  },
  "FEATURE_USER_NEVER_DISPLAY_AGAIN": {
    "EnabledFor": [
      {
        "Name": "FeatureForSpecificUser"
      }
    ]
  }
}

Now I want to be able to get all the FeatureFlags that have a filter in order to display them in a WebPage where the user can modify it.
I could just hardcode them all but I want to try something cleaner and use the FeatureManager to get all the FeatureFlags that have a Filter.
Is it possible?

After more research I found the IFeatureDefinitionProvider
Where we can get all the features and then search for the Desired Filter in the EnabledFor field.
var featureDefinitions = featureDefinitionProvider.GetAllFeatureDefinitionsAsync();
await foreach (var feature in featureDefinitions)
{
    // Lookup for a filter with desired name
    if (feature.EnabledFor.Any(filters => filters.Name == "FeatureForSpecificUser"))
    {
       // do something
    }
}

